# Помощь в настройке роутинга на Ангулар2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4, angular-routing

Господа, добрый день! Нужна помощь в настройке роутинга на втором ангуляре. Видимо я его неправильно понимаю, потому как он работает несколько не так, как ожидалось.

**Собственно вот такое поведение нужно:** есть страница тикетов в виде таблицы, каждое название тикета является ссылкой на сам вопрос, при нажатии на которую страница должна перерисовываться без перезагрузки и показывать детали самого тикета.

**Вот какое поведение есть сейчас:** по сути никакого, потому что криво отрисовывается страница тикетов. Как указано в документации, книгах и информации в интернете, я использую для роутинга тег `router-outlet`, но тикеты отрисовываются не в нем, а под ним и не полностью, как будто что-то стопает работу ангуляра.

**Важный момент - сейчас весь проект работает на AngularJS и я постепенно перевожу его на Angular2, соответсвенно запуск второго ангуляра идет под первым.**

Сам код:
*index.ts*

```
import '../polyfills.ts';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { TicketsAppModule } from './app.module';
import { launched$ } from '../launcher';

declare const process;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

env != 'development' && enableProdMode();

launched$.subscribe(() => {
  if (document.querySelector('[app-module=tickets]'))
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(TicketsAppModule, {ngZone: 'noop'});
})
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared';

import { configInitializer } from 'app/config';

import { TicketsAppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TicketsComponent } from './tickets.component';
import { TicketListComponent } from './list/ticket-list.component';
import { TicketDetailComponent } from './detail/ticket-details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TicketsComponent,
    TicketListComponent,
    TicketDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    TicketsAppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    configInitializer,
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/',
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [TicketsComponent],
})
export class TicketsAppModule { }
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TicketListComponent } from './list/ticket-list.component';
import { TicketDetailComponent } from './detail/ticket-details.component';

declare const I18n: any;

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `${I18n.locale}`,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tickets',
        component: TicketListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'tickets/:id',
        component: TicketDetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TicketsAppRoutingModule { }
```

*tickets.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class TicketsComponent { }
```

**Далее дочерние компоненты**
*ticket-list.component.ts*

```
// привожу не весь код компонента,
// так как там работа с потоками не относящаяся к вопросу
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import template from './ticket-list.tpl.pug';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ticket-list',
    template,
})
export class TicketListComponent implements OnInit {...}
```

*ticket-details.component.ts*

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import template from './ticket-details.tpl.pug';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ticket-detail',
    template,
})
export class TicketDetailComponent { }
```

Сейчас компонент `ticket-list` отрисовывается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если в файле `tickets.component.ts` поменять строку `template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'` на `template: '<app-ticket-list></app-ticket-list>'`, то отрисовываться `ticket-list` уже будет правильно, но при переходе в `ticket-details` будет происходить перезагрузка страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень нужна помощь, идеи кончились, буду благодарен за любой совет!

Comment: судя по коду Ангуляр 5-й версии. Проект создавался с помощью cli? Есть app.component.ts ?

Comment: @LeonidMyronov, нет, не с помощью cli и не мной, сейчас есть два отдельных модуля - касса и тикеты, в каждом свой app.component в тикетах он tickets.commponent, все пробрасывается в первый ангуляр, который ищет элемент с ng-module='tickets' и загружает в него соответсвующий модуль второго ангуляра (ну или пятого)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось просто - дело в том, что в проекте нет зон. Поэтому изменения нужно детектить вручную:

*tickets.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet
    (activate)="onActivate()">
  </router-outlet>`,
})
export class TicketsComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  onActivate(): void {
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
}
```